# Result of catching all 50 Boos?

Tags: luigis-mansion

In Luigi's Mansion, there is a task that you can decide whether to accomplish or not: to catch all the 50 hiding Boos. I am trying to catch all 50 Boos, but I don't want to waste my time on something that might have a simple ending. So, what happens when someone catches all 50 Boos?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you vacuum up the very last Boo, it drops a **[Gold Diamond](http://www.mariowiki.com/Gold_Diamond)**, for 20 000 000 G (more than the value of any other collectible).

Comment: oh wow... That is it?

Comment: @JerryRox Yes, indeed. Isn't everything in a game just another step on the way to 100%, though?